# How to allow users to download content from WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, download, media

I was tasked with the project of setting up a CMS (I chose wordpress) on a private server, from which the client could post media that could be shared with their partners. For instance, there are PSD mockups, .mov files, .swf files, and the occasional .zip package that they would need to share. I have a few different issues.

I'm currently using the FolioGrid Pro theme... as my end result, I'd like the user to be able to view an image preview of the media through the FolioGrid thumbnail view on the main blog, view the media from its specific post, and then be able to download the file from that post. I thought this would be as uploading the media, setting a thumbnail, and then directing the user to right click and save target as. This seems to work with some file types (easy ones... like .png), but with others it does not. For example, the .mov files I have uploaded are showing up just fine within the posts, but when downloaded, it will appear to download a file that has zero data, and when you attempt to open the file it will show up as null.

Also, I get the error 'Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.' when trying to upload some files, such as .zip and .psd. I know these are not wordpress allowed file types, but we're doing all of this on our own private servers, so I need a work around. For the .psds, I tried altering function.php by adding 'psd' => 'image/psd' under allowed file types, but to no avail.

I'm sorry I can't direct you to the site so you can see more specifically what I'm trying to accomplish, but the media being shared is sensitive. What do I do?! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE-----
Hey guys! Thanks for the help. I'm utilizing Download Manager now, and it seems to be helping with some of the files. I'm now able to include a link to a psd file, for instance, and it downloads with no problem.

However, some file types (.mov, .swf) still show up as 0kb files when downloaded. Why might this be happening, when other files are fine?

Answer (score 1):

We have tried many of these Download plugins and after looking into many of them we found [Download Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-manager/) to be best one, It has granular access control and nice download statistics features.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to really tell without seeing the site, but have you looked at some file uploading/downloading plugins for WP? They get around some of the file constraints.

[Here's all of them tagged "download".](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/downloads)

Some are more like for downloading apps, but some are just plain ol' file managers with passwords and such. See if any of them fit your needs, at least should be better than using WP's default media loader which isn't designed for that kind of thing.